# pywebkitgtk crashes application when certain page is loaded into web view

Tags: python, webkit, gtk

I used Python 2.7.2 with py27-webkitgtk 1.1.8 on MacOs Lion.
When i launched my programm with following url: http://weefind.com/blwa/ 
i get error:

** Message: console message: http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1 @43: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

Segmentation fault: 11

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import gtk
import webkit

window = gtk.Window()
view = webkit.WebView()
view.open('http://weefind.com/blwa/')
window.add(view)
window.show_all()
window.connect('delete-event', lambda window, event: gtk.main_quit())

gtk.main()
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uninstall py27-webkitgtk and webkit-gtk, installed with MacPorts, and
build webkitgtk1.3.1 and pywebkitgtk1.1.8 by myself.
Problem solved.